# how to make evacuation time continue to counting until all agents leave the building in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

actually what i'm trying to do is if alarm button is false, turtle will only wander in the enviroment, then when emergency alarm is on, turtle will leave the building and time-to-evacuate will start increment until last of agents leave. i think i can't write the "set time-to-evacuate time-to-evacuate + 1" in the go procedure, because that will make time-to-evacuate is start counting even the emergency alarm is off. thanks. can someone give me an idea how to solve this problem.

```
globals
[
time-to-evacuate
flag-active-alarm
]

to go
ask turtles [wander]
if (flag-active-alarm )[active-alarm] 
tick
end

to wander
[....]
 end

to active-alarm
set flag-active-alarm true
set time-to-evacuate 0
set time-to-evacuate time-to-evacuate + 1
ask turtles [move]

if all? turtles [ pcolor = red ]   ;stops simuation
[ stop ]
end

to move
avoid-obstacles1 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somewhere else in your code, add this:

```
set time-to-evacuate time-to-evacuate + 1
```

wherever you want to the timer to increment. A typical place would be in your `go` procedure:

```
to go
  ...
  set time-to-evacuate time-to-evacuate + 1
  ...
  tick
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i understand what Seth mention, no need to insert set time-to-evacuate 0 in the code, just do like this and it work. thanks a lot.

```
to active-alarm
 set flag-active-alarm true
 set time-to-evacuate time-to-evacuate + 1
 ask turtles [move]
 if all? turtles [ pcolor = red ]   ;stops simuation
 [ stop ]
 end
```